# Define that a "shape" have a static property when accessing the property with instance.constructor?

Tags: typescript

I need to access the static `delay` property of `controller`, from outside itself, i.e. from this utility function:

```typescript
export const useDelay = (controller: DelayController, options?: UseDelayOptions): void => {
  controller.constructor.delays.forEach(delayDef => {});
};
```

Of course, I get:

> Property 'delays' does not exist on type 'Function'.

My `DelayController` defined as this, is obvious wrong (delays definition isn't static ):

```typescript
import type { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

type DelayFunctionOrDelayDefinition = string | { [fn: string]: { delay: number } };

interface DelayController extends Controller {
  delays?: Array<DelayFunctionOrDelayDefinition>;
}
```

How can I type `constructor.delay`?

Comment: I must be missing something but your code doesn't show that `delays` is static? If you want to define a static property with `interface` you'll have to use some workaround...

Comment: @Kokodoko The static delays is accessed from "outside" the class itself in `controller.constructor.delays`

Comment: But `DelayController` is an interface, and `Controller` is probably also an interface? An `interface` can't have anything static I believe... Don't you need the `class` keyword?